# The method multiply(int, int) is undefined for the type Junit

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, junit, undefined

I have typed a simple program in eclipse for Junit testing, but it shows an error: "The method multiply(int, int) is undefined for the type Junit".
package test;

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
class MultiplyTest {

  @Test
  void testMultiply() {
    Junit test=new Junit();
    int result = test.multiply(3,4);
    assertEquals(12,result);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the FQCL of `Junit`? Is this a class that you created? If so, please edit your question to include its code.

Comment: ```Junit``` must be one of your classes, which does not define the multiply method(int, int) method. There is no ```Junit``` class within the ```JUnit Testframework```. Most likely you will find this class within your package ```test````

Comment: please post the Junit class also in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you written import for Junit class in MultiplyTest class? and What is the package name of Junit class? and i think @Test annotated method should be public.